# Mostrar datos de un UNION de manera horizontal

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una estructura ya definida del modo siguiente el cual se compone de 2 tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Y  la segunda es:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  venta INT,
  cliente_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_ventas_clientes FOREIGN KEY(cliente_id) REFERENCES clientes(id),
  cliente_id2 INT
);
```

Los datos que almacena clientes son:

```
INSERT INTO clientes(nombre)
VALUES
("uno"),
("dos"),
("tres");
```

Y ventas:

```
INSERT INTO ventas(venta, cliente_id, cliente_id2)
VALUES
(12, 1, 2),
(15, 2, 1),
(20, 3, 1);
```

Mi deseo es obtener un resultado como este:

```
nombre  venta  nombre
uno     12      dos
dos     15      uno
tres    20      uno
```

Sin embargo lo que mas he conseguido es esto a través de un `JOIN`:

```
SELECT nombre, venta
FROM clientes
JOIN ventas
ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id
UNION
SELECT nombre as nombre2, venta as venta2
FROM clientes
JOIN ventas
ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id2;
```

Pero me muestra los resultados verticales y yo los quiero horizontales:

```
nombre  venta
uno     12
dos     15
tres    20
dos     12
uno     15
uno     20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solo usa alias a la tabla y puedes hacerle join varias veces con varios campos

```
SELECT clientes1.nombre , venta, clientes2.nombre
FROM ventas
JOIN clientes AS clientes1 ON ventas.cliente_id = clientes1.id
JOIN clientes AS clientes2 ON ventas.cliente_id2 = clientes2.id
```

Comment: mira que perfecto, lo había intentado similar pero pase por alto totalmente ponerle un alias a la misma tabla y pues que te digo salió como lo esperaba, en un momento te acepto la respuesta.